# Ошибка "YOu must call this method on a background thread" в Glide

Tags: android, glide

Здравствуйте. 
Только начал работать с библиотекой [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) и столкнулся с проблемой загрузки данных в `ArrayList`. Сейчас все выглядит так:

```
class GetBitmaps extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ... 
        bitmaps.add(Glide.with(context).load(url).asBitmap().into(5, 5).get());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ...
    }
}
```

При этом, в строке, добавляющей элементы в `ArrayList`, выдается `Exception`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: YOu must call this method on a background thread
```

Но ведь он и так выполняется в отдельном потоке, разве нет? Ладно, решил переделать в отдельный поток - та же самая ошибка. Что я делаю не так?

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: вы скорее всего неправильно вызываете свой AsyncTesk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394484/3212712):

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(url)
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(5, 5) {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
        bitmaps.add(resource); // Возможно надо обернуть в runOnUiThread()
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Видел тот пост, но почему-то не заметил этого варианта в конце.